# Python - Sort column ascending - using groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

The following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_original=pd.DataFrame({\
'race_num':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3],\
'race_position':[2,3,0,1,0,0,2,3,0],\
'percentage_place':[77,55,88,50,34,56,99,12,75]
})
```

Gives an output of:

| race_num | race_position | percentage_place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 77 |
| 1 | 3 | 55 |
| 1 | 0 | 88 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 0 | 34 |
| 2 | 0 | 56 |
| 2 | 2 | 99 |
| 3 | 3 | 12 |
| 3 | 0 | 75 |

I need to mainpulate this dataframe to keep the `race_num` grouped but sort the percentage place in ascending order - and the `race_position` is to stay aligned with the original `percentage_place`.

Desired out is:

| race_num | race_position | percentage_place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 88 |
| 1 | 2 | 77 |
| 1 | 3 | 55 |
| 2 | 2 | 99 |
| 2 | 0 | 56 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 0 | 34 |
| 3 | 0 | 75 |
| 3 | 3 | 12 |

My attempt is:

```
df_new = df_1.groupby(['race_num','race_position'])\['percentage_place'].nlargest().reset_index()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you mean "descending" here? "sort the percentage place in ascending order"

Comment: Ah yes descending - your correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

```py
In [137]: df_original.sort_values(['race_num', 'percentage_place'], ascending=[True, False])
Out[137]:
   race_num  race_position  percentage_place
2         1              0                88
0         1              2                77
1         1              3                55
6         2              2                99
5         2              0                56
3         2              1                50
4         2              0                34
8         3              0                75
7         3              3                12
```